# Navigating in numeric bullets in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I have a list of questions numbered by numeric bullets like

1. s
2. s
3. s

Each bullet point is of variable length (from few lines to few pages). This makes me to scroll a lot to go to next bullet. I felt I can reformat to bullet to "Q.X." from "X." and search (Ctrl+F) for "Q." ans this will take me to next bullet point each time I hit next search result. However this trick didnt work as Word does not search in list's bullet text. That is it gives no searches for "Q.X." in list bullets but gives searches for "Q." whenever it appears in actual text/paragraphs.

So what option I am left with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL6OG.png)If you do a Find>Advanced Find>Format (down at the bottom) >Style>List Paragraph you should then be able to move to each of the next bullets.

Comment: nope didnt work. Did it work for you?

Comment: it did...i added a screen shot. nothing is highlighted when you went to do your find was it?

Comment: nope, this is what I am doing: http://s8.postimg.org/ajzjfevrp/Untitled4.png

Comment: ok, what if you just number with regular formatting (get rid of the Q) and then do a find like i did in my picture

Comment: still no :( http://s29.postimg.org/5z9lelixj/Untitled4.png

Comment: you have something in the find. have nothing highlighted

Comment: yeah its working even on `Q.` good hack, though I dont get exactly how it is working...It just takes you to next bullet points thats whal all Find Style: List Paragraph means?